# Is there an inverse function of SetProcessDPIAware with support for Windows 7? Or how to return to what was?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, winapi, dpi

I use the `SetProcessDPIAware()` function from `user32.dll` in my WinForms application. After calling `SetProcessDPIAware()`, I need to return to the previous DPI awareness for the process.

I read the article [Setting the default DPI awareness for a process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/C9488338-D863-45DF-B5CB-7ED9B869A5E2). `SetProcessDpiAwareness()` and `SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext()` do not work with Windows 7 or Windows Vista.

How do I return to the previous DPI awareness for a process after calling of `SetProcessDPIAware()` for it?

Comment: I don't recommend doing it, but the documentation [explicitly lists cases where Windows will forcibly reset DPI awareness](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows#common-pitfalls-win32) ("Forced reset of process-wide DPI awareness"). Rather than somehow using this as a hack, though (which could not be guaranteed to keep working as-is in newer versions), it's worth reconsidering your design. For example, you could farm tasks out to child processes.

Comment: How it works? I send a message like PostMessage(this.Handle, WM_DPICHANGED, (IntPtr)(wParam), (IntPtr)(lParam)) to my window, but nothing happens. Or should I write a WM_DPICHANGED message handler? I read the article https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/hidpi/wm-dpichanged. It looks like it works for Windows 8 and later versions.

Answer (score 0):

As an option, you can restart application and based on a setting or command line argument, decide if you want to set process DPI aware.

You can create a boolean user setting property in `Settings` file under `Properties` folder. This setting will determine if the DPI-awareness is enabled. Then when the application starts, check if the setting is enabled, then call `SetProcessDPIAware`:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
static class Program
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool SetProcessDPIAware();

    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6 &&
            Properties.Settings.Default.DPIAware)
            SetProcessDPIAware();

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(true);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

Also in the main UI form, you can check the setting and show a message like the following and allow user to restart the application by enabling or disabling DPI-awareness. To do so,  it's enough to set the setting value, save the settings and call `Application.Restart()`:

[image]

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Properties.Settings.Default.DPIAware)
        toolStripLabel1.Text = "DPI-awareness is enabled. Restart to disable DPI-awareness.";
    else
        toolStripLabel1.Text = "DPI-awareness is disabled. Restart to enable DPI-awareness.";
}
private void toolStripLabel1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.DPIAware = !Properties.Settings.Default.DPIAware;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    Application.Restart();
}
```

Don't forget to create the DPIAware settings which will tell us whether we want to call `SetProcessDPIAware` in `main` method:

[image]

Comment: I would like to use it differently:
SetProcessDPIAware();
/* do something; */
UndoSetProcessDPIAware();

Comment: I see, but I '*guess*' you need to restart the process, like VS is doing so. That's why I shared it '*as an option*'.